# SharePoint 2013 Excel Services : Unable To Refresh Reports With Odata Feeds

Tags: sharepoint

I have created Excel Charts(Power Pivot) using OData feeds only.But facing issue to refresh the file data.Below are the configuration i have done:

1. Secure Store Account (Unattended Service Account):

   - Account Name: **ODataAccount**  (Credential are OK ,checked with admin  )
2. Excel Service Application:

   - Trusted File Location
   - Global Setting > External Data > Unattanted Service Account > **ODataAccount**
3. Excel File Connection Settings

   - Data > Connections > 'MyConnection' > Definition > Authentication Settings > Use a Stored Account **ODataAccount**
   - Data > Connections > 'WorkbookDataModel' > No Changes
4. Uploaded the file To document library
5. Created Web part page > added Excel Web Access Web Part > Configured the Excel Chart > Excel Chart can be seen

***Error/Issue:***

Error on refreshing connection within Excel Web Access WP:

*An error occurred while working on the data model in the workbook.Please try again.
We were unable to refresh one or more data connections in this workbook.The following connection failed to refresh:**ThisWorkBookDataModel***

***Please help to resolve this & with below queries :***

1. Is this possible to refresh OData feeds in Excel Data from Excel Web Access Web Part/ Excel Web App ?
2. If yes:

   - Please let me know what are the prerequisites for the same.
   - Please help to provide some link or article to configure same

Comment: According to this: http://tavislovell.com/create-a-dashboard-from-your-sharepoint-list-data-using-excel-services-and-the-excel-web-access-web-part/ it should be possible, however there are others claiming Excel Services does not support OData as a data source, see answer from @Venkatesh Mandalapa below

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately OData is not a supported data source for Excel Services in SharePoint 2013.

**Reference**: https://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj819452.aspx